# Hive: How to delimit rows using a string literal

Tags: hadoop, hive

Need help here.
This is related to hive.

i have a text file with a single long line, for e.g:
JASON   29\SASHA   24\CHRISTINE   15\ROBERT   20\

Now i need to create a table in hive, whose rows are delimited using "\" (backslash), like if i insert the data from the above mentioned line "JASON   29\SASHA   24...." i would want 4 rows to be inseted in my table.

in other words, i want my custom char to be row delimiters, and not the default "\n".

i wrote the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE newline_tab
(
 name STRING,
 age INT
)

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\'  
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

but i am unable to create the table, and im getting following error:

> FAILED: SemanticException 9:20 LINES TERMINATED BY only supports newline '\n' right now. Error encountered near token ''\''

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: if only '\n' is supported, then i don't think there is any better solution than replacing "\" with "\n" in your document. What version and distribution of hive are you using?

Comment: Hi Raj, im using cdh5, with hive version 0.12.0

Comment: Actually i have a document, from our client, which is has a string "\" separating the rows, and they want this file data to be loaded in hive table. its a huge file.

Comment: Either you can replace '\' with `\n` using simple Unix commands and then proceed to load by using `\n` as the line termination character. Otherwise, you have to write a custom Serde to handle the line termination character of your choice. More information on creating a Serde can be found [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-use-a-serde-in-apache-hive/)

Comment: @visakh Serdes don't decide what a record is. He needs a custom `InputFormat` and `RecordReader`.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee ( eid int, name String,
salary String, destination String)
COMMENT ‘Employee details’
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\t’
LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Comment: A little explanation to your code would be appreciated!